# Unit testing a controller method with parameter validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I am looking to write a unit test for a controller method defined as follows (the actual regex is much more complex, it's simplified here)

```
  [HttpGet, Route(@"/abc/{X}/{Y}")] /*,  
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(
            [FromRoute, Required, RegularExpression(@"^[\w]{4,12}$")]  string X,
            [FromRoute, Required, RegularExpression(@"^[\w]{2,24}$")]  string Y
            )
        {
             ... 
        }
```

Now, as noted in other questions, the validation doesn't work from unit tests. However I'm hoping someone could shed some light on how to do a unit test for code that's using top-level parameters as shown above, as all discussion I've found so far focused around model validation.

FWIW, I'm using Net 5.

Comment: Not sure if it's easy to achieve using the attributes, but you may be interested in a library like Guard (https://github.com/safakgur/guard) or FluentValidation ( https://fluentvalidation.net/). These allow you to keep the validation rules easy to write and read and have them in the body of your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this  by elevating the test to an Integration test, using the [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) and [IntegrationFixture](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConnectingApps.IntegrationFixture/) as [explained in this article on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5268823/Testing-Validation-Attributes-with-xUnit).

In general, it's something like this (just a few snippets in case the link dies):

1. Create an interface:

```
     public interface IMyAPI
        {
            [Get("/abc/{X},{Y}")]
            Task<ApiResponse<string>> Get( string X, string Y);
        }
```

2. Use it in unit test:

```
     using (var fixture = new RefitFixture<Startup, IMyAPI>(RestService.For<IMyAPI>))
            {
                var refitClient = fixture.GetRefitClient();
                var response = await refitClient.Get(X, Y);
                ...
             }
```